# Creating an array using a Do While loop (with input validation)

Tags: c++, validation, c++11, do-while

I am making a C++ code where you will create an array using a `do` `while` loop.
Here is the full code:

```cpp
const int size = 10;
    
    double *pt1; 
    //executable
    pt1=new double[size];

    int i = 0;
    do{
        cout <<"mile" << "[" << i << "]" << setw(3);
        if(*(pt1+i) >= 100 && *(pt1+i) <= 250)
        {
            cin >> *(pt1+i);
            i++;
        }   
        else if( *(pt1+i) > 100 && *(pt1+i) < 250)
        {
           cout << "100-250 only";
            continue;
        }
    }while(i < 10);
```

There is an input validation where the numbers that will be accepted are only numbers from 100 to 250 but it keeps on looping. I can't find where the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to be too smart with pointer arithmetic.   Instead of `*(pt1 + i)` use `pt1[i]`.   The standard specifies they are equivalent and there is little to gain using the first form other than code unreadability or boasting rights among rank amateurs.     Also (as to the question you asked) you are testing elements of the (dynamically allocated) array before initialising or reading values to them, so your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the tip bro!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error is that you are testing the value of the input **before** you actually get the input. That makes no sense, you need to switch the order around. So this

```
    if(*(pt1+i) >= 100 && *(pt1+i) <= 250)
    {
        cin >> *(pt1+i);
        ...
    }   
    else if( *(pt1+i) > 100 && *(pt1+i) < 250)
    {
        ...
    }
```

should be this

```
    cin >> *(pt1+i);
    if(*(pt1+i) >= 100 && *(pt1+i) <= 250)
    {
        ...
    }   
    else if( *(pt1+i) > 100 && *(pt1+i) < 250)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Secondly I think you meant

```
else if( *(pt1+i) < 100 || *(pt1+i) > 250)
```

Or better you could have just said

```
else
```

Then there is no chance of getting the logic wrong. When you have only two choices, you just need to test for the first choice and use `else` for the second choice. There's no need to test for the opposite of the first choice, using a plain `else` will do that automatically.

Also `continue` at the end of a loop is not necessary, loops continue automatically.

Finally `pt1[i]` is much easier to read than `*(pt1+i)`.

Comment: i think OP wants to validate after reading the value, not before ;)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes, I'll add something about that as well

Comment: worth mentioning that checking the range already covers the case of user entering not a double. Wouldnt be the case if `0` was a valid input

Comment: @john I see. I remembered as well the first error you said when I was eating earlier! Thanks for the tip!